# How do i scrape data from an aspx site, __doPostBack form?

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I'm trying to crawl/scrape a website using c# console app, getting the initial page is not a problem, but I need to get pages when I click on the button who has the __doPostBack action.

I try with these settings but this already back results from the initial page:

I Update my code

```
            var client1 = new RestClient("https://example.com");
            var request1 = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            IRestResponse initialResponse = client1.Execute(request1);


            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(initialResponse.Content);

            var formData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            formData.Add("__EVENTTARGET", "ctl00$MainContentExample");
            formData.Add("__EVENTARGUMENT", "");
            formData.Add("ctl00$MainContent$CustomHiddenField", "");
            formData.Add("__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR", "B5682C7D");
            var divViewState = doc.DocumentNode
                .SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='__VIEWSTATE']").Attributes[3].Value;
            formData.Add("__VIEWSTATE", divViewState);
            var divEventValidation = doc.DocumentNode
                .SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='__EVENTVALIDATION']").Attributes[3].Value;
            formData.Add("__EVENTVALIDATION", divEventValidation);


            var client = new RestClient("https://example.com");
            var request = new RestRequest("/methodName",Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");

            var c = "";
            var i = 0;
            foreach (var cookie in initialResponse.Cookies)
            {
                if(i==0)
                 c += cookie.Name + "=" + cookie.Value + "; ";
                else
                    c += cookie.Name + "=" + cookie.Value;

                i++;
            }
            request.AddHeader("Cookie", c);
           request.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
            request.AddHeader("Host", "example.com");
            request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3");
            request.AddHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.AddHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Encoding", "utf-8");

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(formData);
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

            request.AddHeader("Content-Length", byteData.Length.ToString())


            request.AddParameter("undefined", byteData, ParameterType.RequestBody);

            IRestResponse response2 = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: Have you tried comparing the POST request from a browser to the POST request from your console app to see what is different? If so could add this information to your question?

Comment: I get the values from a browser from the post request, [link]http://prntscr.com/puxapl and add in variables in my app. But in responsebody variable I get the initial page not the results from paging.

Comment: Have you tried capturing the POST request from a browser using a web proxy such as https://www.telerik.com/fiddler and then capturing POST request from your console app for the same operation also using fiddler and comparing them? There doesn't seem to be enough code in the question to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I get data from post request and create now request with cookies. But again 
 the response is from the initial page. This is my code now:

Comment: Would you be able to provide a reproducible example of your problem there are some tips here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I send a request with the Postman app and there are results of the second request. The same request I send with C# but this shows me an internal server error. The Postman request is: [link]https://prnt.sc/q38bjb?fbclid , my request is [link]https://prnt.sc/q38a5z?fbclid

Comment: Have you checked the antixsrf token is correct?

Comment: Yes, I get from the first request. I Update my code above, just links are different from the site.

Answer (score 0):

Use RestRequest.AddParameter instead of RestRequest.AddHeader

https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/RestSharp/RestRequest/AddHeader/php-restrequest-addheader-method-examples.html

https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/RestSharp/RestRequest/AddParameter/php-restrequest-addparameter-method-examples.html

Comment: I say this because in your Postman inspection, you have those properties listed as parameters. I think these are transferred as URL Encoded parameters separated by the & symbol. Headers are in the meta-data of the payload and are interpreted differently.

Comment: I change with AddParametar but the response is the same. Return the initial page and show me Error: ** "Exception:Caught: "'' is not a supported encoding name. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method." (System.ArgumentException)
A System.ArgumentException was caught: "'' is not a supported encoding name. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method."**